# Git Web interface in Node.js

Tags: node.js, git

I'm looking for a good Git web interface and management interface in Node.JS. I've found Gitalist, but I would like to have it in Node.JS instead if there is already something out there and nice.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Because that's what I want it to be in. If I wanted PHP I would ask for PHP or Python or Perl. But I want it to be in Node.JS. Simple request.

Answer (score 3):

[Ungit](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit)?

Needs additional characthers.

Comment: It's cool, but I don't think it's quite what I'm looking for. It runs on a local directory Git repo instead of a panel that manages a remote Git repo or a web viewer per say.